# websocket parser error in Node JS Socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have got following warning in my Node JS application :
warn - websocket parser error: continuation frame cannot follow current opcode

It has occurred only once but I have no clue what it was about.

Does anybody have idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of node / ws are you using? I had this same warning (intermittently) when using an old version of ws (0.8.2) with a modern node (6.9.1). I upgraded to ws 1.1.1 (same node version) and never saw this again. Hope this helps.